# Character space of $L^{1} (\mathbb Z)$

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-algebras

I have a question about  the Gelfand and norm topologies  on the character space of  $L^{1} (\mathbb Z)$.

> Are the Gelfand and norm topologies equal, on the character space of
>   $L^{1} (\mathbb Z)$?

Comment: What's the motivation for this question? What have you tried? Why doesn't it work?

Comment: Which Banach algebra are we speaking about? A discrete $L^1$ with pointwise multiplication? Or a group algebra with convolution? The original poster ought to clarify this point from the onset.

Answer (score 0):

Based on Proposition 3.10, pp. 67 of the following Book

"Functional Analysis and infinite-dimensional geometry By Vaclav Zizler and ...Springer 2001",

if $X$ is an infinite-dimensional normed space, then weak and norm topologies do not coincide. 
Because $L^{1}(\mathbb{Z})^{*}$ is an infinite-dimensional normed space by using the mentioned theorem the Gelfand and norm topologies are not equal.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE! The reference is accurate, but it'd be best if you wrote the proposition explicitly, because this site prefers self-sufficient answers.