# The Gelfand and norm topologies are equal on the character space of $L^1(\mathbb Z)$

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-algebras

We know that the character space of the Banach algebra $L^{1}(\mathbb Z)$ is homeomorphic to the unit circle $\mathbb T$, but I can't show that the Gelfand and norm topologies are equal on that.

Comment: @hamidkamali "[Homeomorphic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homeomorphism)" was correct, while "homomorphic" would not be.

Comment: @OP Note that your question has already been asked [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/451043), although it hasn't been answered there either. Also, what have you tried?